# detect event on 2 overlapping sibling elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 2 overlapping siblings like this:

```js
document.querySelector("#item1").addEventListener('mouseup',()=>{
    console.log("Mouseup item 1!");
});

document.querySelector("#item2").addEventListener('mouseup',()=>{
console.log("Mouseup item 2!")
},true);
```

```css
#item1{
  height:10rem;
  width:10rem;
  background-color:red;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-2;
  
}

#item2{
  height:10rem;
  width:10rem;
  background-color:green;
  position:relative;
  top:2rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="item1"></div>
<div id="item2"></div>
```

whenever I `mouseup` on item2 I want item1 mouseup event to also be triggered if mouse is within item1

( Basically I want `mouseup` to be triggered on whatever divs the mouse is within regardless of which is overlapping what )

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Listen mouseup on the parent element of the divs.

Comment: @Teemu will that give me which divs the mouse was in?

Comment: Sure, pass the event object to the [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#the_event_listener_callback), and retrieve the target from `event.target`. To detect the overlapping elements you can use [elementsFromPoint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementsFromPoint).

Comment: @Teemu did you mean something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/oq4Lgpw2/49/) ?

Comment: You seem to have a solution. Could you put it into an answer so that other people can find it later on?

Comment: @AHaworth I was actually waiting if someone had a better solution but sure I'll add it

Answer (score 2):

Using `elementsFromPoint` as 'pointed out' by  @Teemu in the comments I came up with this:

```js
document.querySelector("#wrapper").addEventListener('mouseup', (event) => {
  let els = document.elementsFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY);
  els.forEach(el => {
    if (el.id != '' && el.id != 'wrapper')
      console.log(el.id)
  })
});
```

```css
#item1 {
  height: 10rem;
  width: 10rem;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
}

#item2 {
  height: 10rem;
  width: 10rem;
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
  top: 2rem;
}

#wrapper {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 20rem;
  width: 20rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="item1"></div>
  <div id="item2"></div>
</div>
```